# ListView doesn't separate objects from doc

Tags: flutter, user-interface, listview

I'm trying to create scrollable list of posts, but instead i got static non-scrollable bloc of strings, which is overflowing.

1. Example:

[image]

2. Oveflowing:

[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _writePost,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.create, color: Colors.grey[300]),
        ),
        body: SizedBox(
            child: Container(
                child: Column(children: [
          StreamBuilder<List<Post>>(
            initialData: const [],
            stream: _socketStream.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (_isLoading) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
               ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  ...snapshot.data!.map<Widget>(
                    (post) => Padding(
                      key: ValueKey(post.id),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          post.content,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        trailing: MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _deletePost(post.id);
                          },
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.delete,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ]))));
  }
```

**Moreover, they all go like a single card, without separating**.
[image]

**Edited code, which is scrolling but doesn't separate posts**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _writePost,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.create, color: Colors.grey[300]),
        ),
        body: SizedBox(
          height: 500, 
          child:
              StreamBuilder<List<Post>>(
            initialData: const [],
            stream: _socketStream.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (_isLoading) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              return Card(child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  ...snapshot.data!.map<Widget>(
                    (post) => Padding(
                      key: ValueKey(post.id),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          post.content,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        trailing: MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _deletePost(post.id);
                          },
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.delete,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
               ) );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
```

I'm tried to find error with documentation, but...

Comment: Have you tried wrapping de SizedBox with a SIngleChildScrollView?

Comment: @LuisUtrera Thanks, its work for scrolling, but i still got problem of separating posts. They all go like 1 big document.

Comment: you mean space between each tile? For that you might use ListView.separated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Column` and `Listview` take the maximum available height. therefore, the height of Listview which here is a child of Column should be constrained. You can do so by wrapping your ListView inside `Expanded`:

```
child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
```

Also, if your list is long, it is not recommended to set `shrinkwrap` to true. Because it makes the `ListView` to load all its items when the layout gets built. So it can slow down performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _writePost,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.create, color: Colors.grey[300]),
        ),
        body: SizedBox(
           height: MediaQuery.of(context).height*0.8,  // add this line 
            child: 
          // Container(        // do not need this
          //                   child:   // and this do not need    
          // Column(children: [      // and this do not need 
          StreamBuilder<List<Post>>(
            initialData: const [],
            stream: _socketStream.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (_isLoading) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
               ListView(  // change this to ListView.builder for more performance
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  ...snapshot.data!.map<Widget>(
                    (post) => Padding(
                      key: ValueKey(post.id),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          post.content,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        trailing: MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _deletePost(post.id);
                          },
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.delete,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );## Heading ##
            },
          ),
       // ]) // comment this
       // ).  // and comment this
     )
   );
  }
```

Comment: no need to single child scroll view.